# Java get element from List while the size is changing

Tags: java, list, arraylist

For example, I have a list of strings say:

```
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
strs.add("A");
strs.add("B");
strs.add("C");
strs.add("D");
```

I want to loop over the list and get some elements, but at the same time, I want to remove some elements. Let's say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++) {
    String element = strs.get(i);
    System.out.println(element);
    strs.remove("A")
}
```

In the above example, element would be "A", "C", "D". But what I want is "A", "B", "C", "D". The above code is just an example, there could be other elements I want to remove, such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++) {
    String element = strs.get(i);
    System.out.println(element);
    if (condition A) { strs.remove("A"); }
    if (condition B) { strs.remove("B"); }
    if (condition D) { strs.remove("D"); }
}
```

In this case, the size of the List `strs` would change depends on different conditions. And sometimes `element` jump from "A" to "C" without "B". What I have tried so far is created a list of indexes in my notebook. I know that remove element "A" will make the for loop ignore "B", but when this comes to other cases, the indexes don't work anymore. Is there a final algorithm or solution that can check every element inside the for loop?

Notice: Without using Iterator, List.removeAll, or i-- (Since I sometimes get Time Limit Exceed when use i--).

Comment: You'll want to use an iterator and `remove()`. Or just put `i--` after you've removed an element in your for loop.

Comment: @user7 I took a look at that answer, but is there a way without using iterator and remove all?

Comment: Looks like a XY problem. It's more likely that the TLE is caused by your algorithm being wrong (or just not fast enough), not `i--`. Alternatively look for how to filter a list.